# Why isn't <body> expanding to fit its contents?

Tags: css

I have a table that extends off the edge of the screen, but the body only gets as wide as the screen, causing the table to overflow it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6REkj/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            table { background-color: lime; }
            body { border: 2px solid blue; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is one of those things that make me think CSS is broken. I thought containing elements were supposed to expand to fit their contents.

**Question 1:** Why is it doing that?

**Question 2:** What should I do to get a margin between the table and the right edge of the page?

Comment: How can it fit the contents?  What do you expect the table cells to do?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

if you set `display:table;` to `body` or `html`, it will allow to grow its width over the 100% of viewport. it will just expand like a `table` does :)

```
html {display:table;width:100%; /* need to set a width to 100%, wich means here a min-width since it is displayed with the same specifities thas has a table , it shrinks and expand according to its content */}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6REkj/1/

other options :

- `display:inline-block;min-width:100%;` on `body` : http://jsfiddle.net/6REkj/3/
- `position:absolute;min-width:100%;` on `html` : http://jsfiddle.net/6REkj/4/

---

> **Edit** nowdays, `min-width:max-content` would do . http://jsfiddle.net/bj4wk6m2/

Comment: Seems weird to me to have to do that, but it appears to work well, so thank you.

Comment: if it seems weird to you, you may use another value of display on body only : body {display:inline-block;min-width:100%;margin:0; } http://jsfiddle.net/6REkj/3/  or position html out of the regular flow : html  {position:absolute;min-width:100%;} http://jsfiddle.net/6REkj/4/ (display:table; seemed to be the most logical to me :) )

Comment: Cool. I think I'll stick with the display:table unless some other problem comes up.

Comment: its worth mentioning that `display: inline-flex; min-width: 100%;` on `body` seems to work as well

Comment: @GeorgeMauer `inline-table` too actually ;) but width:100% again since it is about the table-layout algorythm

Answer (score 9):

It's very strange that the simplest solution hasn't been mentioned:

```
body {
  width: fit-content;
  min-width: 100%; /* because the content might only be a few words */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* because 100% + padding > 100% */
}
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work everywhere and it still requires prefixing. In Chrome (with Blink these days) that would be: `-webkit-fit-content` (`-webkit-` in Blink, weird).

Comment: This is definitly the right answer. You can skip border-box though and just do `min-width: 100vh` which will be 100% of the viewport.

Answer (score 5):

CSS isn't broken, [the behaviour you are seeing is by design](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#blockwidth).

Some quotes from the link above:

> The following constraints must hold among the used values of the other properties:
>
> 'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' = width of containing block
>
> ..
>
> If 'width' is set to 'auto', any other 'auto' values become '0' and 'width' follows from the resulting equality.

From this I understand that block level elements have a default width of `100%` of their containing block if all of the other properties are not set.

`<body>` is by default a block level element.

You could set `float: left;` or `display: inline-block` on `body` and it will grow with its content.

Here's a <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6REkj/2/)</kbd>.

To answer question 2 (to get the result of the accepted answer without resorting to setting `display: table` on an element which isn't a `table`), you could do it this way:

**CSS:**

```
html {
    padding: 10px;
}
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
}
body {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
table, p {
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

Here's a <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6REkj/5/)</kbd>.

Comment: @GCyrillus - My pleasure, [your last fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6REkj/4/) is the best way to fix this I believe.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution for this is to have a vertical scrollbar.
It can be achieved with an additional `div`, wrapping the `table`.

**This would be the css:**

```
body { border: 2px solid blue; }
table, p { background-color: cyan; width: 100%; word-wrap:break-word;}
div { width: 100%; overflow-x: auto;}
```

If you would only have the `p`-Tag, the attribute `word-wrap:break-word;` helps.
You can also move the paragraph outside the `div`, which allows you to see the whole content without scrolling.

See the fiddle for a working sulution:

http://jsfiddle.net/WrbpJ/

**If you prefer scrolling the whole page, and not only the div, this can be used:**

```
body { border: 2px solid blue; display: table;}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sGH4t/

If you don't want the scrollbar at all, you'll have to use lists or divs instead of a table.

Answer (score -1):

The way you have used tr and td tags, the data in table is bound to overflow.

You have to decide how many rows and colmuns your table should have, when you are using simple html table. just put tr and td tags accordingly, and then you are done.http://jsfiddle.net/6REkj/`Fiddle`