# What is the deal with the size of HTML and body when simulating a mobile device in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile

I recently tried to load a tool on my phone that I develop that is hosted internally where I work.

A few things looked off, which I expected. But one particular element seemed to be extra odd.

I eventually loaded the page in Chrome on a MacBook Pro and used the "Device Toolbar" feature to render it in my Desktop browser like it would on a phone. To keep a private application private I will demonstrate with Google.com. This is what I see:

[image]

That's the `body` element highlighted in blue. The `html` element is the same.

This is what I see in my application too and explains what I'm seeing when actually using my phone.

I can't, for the life of me, understand why these elements chose this size. There is no explicit "width" for these elements, nor is there "max-width" etc. Nothing that I can see that should cause this behavior.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

---

### UPDATE

It appears that there is some odd behavior with Dev Tools. Proper mobile testing probably shouldn't be done this way (Feel free to change my mind, Google...) but the issue stands that sometimes, the body element doesn't stretch to accommodate its content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, block-level elements, including `<body>`, do not expand to fit their content, but rather will expand to the width of its container.  See [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#blockwidth) for detailed information.

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xnr6buaf/4/) demonstrating this.  If you resize the panels/window you'll see the body width changing based on the viewport, but the content width has absolutely no effect.

This SO question has more information: [Why isn't <body> expanding to fit its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21389073/why-isnt-body-expanding-to-fit-its-contents)

Another issue that's not helping is related to the Chrome dev tools device toolbar.  Changing the zoom, disabling and re-enabling the device toolbar and its settings can be buggy and is not always reliable.  I have spent hours chasing issues that didn't actually exist because the device toolbar functionality misled me.

[image: google chrome dev tools zoomed in via device toolbar]